# MATLAB - convert from normalised figure units to axis data units

Tags: matlab

I am manually drawing an annotation onto a figure in MATLAB (via insert --> line) and I would like to know how to convert from its position in normalised figure units to axis data units. This is the reverse of an operation that is commonly solved by functions around the internet. However, I am unclear as to how MATLAB converts from axis data units to normalised figure units.

Comment: The answer is different depending on how the data is normalised. You need to show the normalisation code you are using, and explain in more detail what is preventing you performing the reverse normalisation.

Comment: I am literally drawing a line onto the figure manually (via insert --> line), and MATLAB reports the position of that line in normalised figure units. So I am not converting it myself. With regard to the reverse normalisation, I am not sure how the default MATLAB normalisation works. Thanks